# Adding CSS to and added input elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm new to JavaScript. I managed to add dynamic inputs after clicking on a button but I want to know how to apply the CSS to those added inputs, if anyone can give me a simple example i'd be glad!
Thank you!

Comment: Like... inline styles?  Don't.  Add a class and style that.

Comment: I agree with @BenPotter, but if you can't change your .css file, you can always use http://api.jquery.com/css/ `$.css` if you have a design library like jQuery

Comment: I already did that , but the inputs that are added when you click on the add button, have no style !

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
<button onclick="newInput()">Add new input</button>

function newInput() {
    var newElement = document.createElement("input");
    newElement.className = "newClass";
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

And in the `style` section, or in the `.css` file, you'll have:

```
.newClass {
  /*Styles go here*/
    display: block;
}
```

Fiddle example of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/8zen9wwo/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example using jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/kmrvpz99/

Html Code

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Javascript Code

```
$('.container').append('<input type="text" class="yourstyle">');
var manualCss = $('<input type="text">').css('background-color', '#333');
$('.container').append(manualCss);
```

The css File

```
.yourstyle {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

By defining .yourstyle in the css file, all elements on the html site that possess this class, even those dynamically added via javascript, will use this style. You can however manually modify the css by setting the style attribute on the element directly.